# Is it possible to merge my two Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Can I merger my two accounts (Bo Lawson, lilfuzzybunny 007) after one was lost from being hacked. Google finished their investigation and returned control of my account to me?? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please see: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Izzy

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of your previous enquiry. We moderators cannot manually merge accounts, the only thing the user can do is to follow the existing procedure and wait patiently.

Comment: @Andrew T. Oh I see, I apologize I overlooked the form you posted in your answer.